# How to specify audience for OAuth token in SF when configuring auth for an Azure protected API endpoint hosting external data?

Tags: oauth2, external-services, azure, azure-active-directory

I have an external data source hosted in Azure which is an OData API endpoint. Everything works well with auth disabled.

I created an application registration in Azure AD to represent the API and [Exposed an API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis#add-a-scope) which gave me an Application ID URI. This URI is what I am supposed to use when requesting a token from AAD for the endpoint.

Inside the External Data source authentication section I have added the .default scope for the Application ID URI which I exposed which looks like `api://<client id guid>/.default`, expecting the token generated by Salesforce to include it and use it to set the audience.

Instead, the token which is generated is using the AAD Graph API (00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000) as the resource it is requesting a token for, which is causing my API to declare the token to be invalid. I can get around this in my API by setting the allowed audience for the token to be the Graph API, but that is not right - the token should be generated using the audience of the API rather than the AAD Graph Api.

I tried supplying the App ID URI as a query string parameter in the Auth Providers config - something that I've had to do in the past to get Postman to work - but that isn't working either.

TLDR: how can I configure Salesforce to use a non-graph api audience when configuring OAuth protection for an API endpoint hosted in Azure?

Comment: External Data source is used in conjunction with [Salesforce Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.platform_connect_about.htm&type=5), a paid add-on product. Do you have Connect?

Comment: Yes, and before I added auth I was able to source the data via API and work with it. Trouble is just with getting a valid audience in the token

Comment: You can try defining the token via a Named Credential, it lets you specify the audience. Haven't tried it with Connect but in theory this should work. See [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.platform_connect_external_data_source_example.htm&type=5)